# Finding one integral directly from our knowledge of another similar integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

We are given two integrals, $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$, defined as follows

$$ I_{1}= \int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}} \frac{df_{1}(z)}{dz} \ f_{2}(z) \ \cos[g(z)] \ dz \ = \text{known value}\tag{1}$$
$$ I_{2}= \int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}} \frac{df_{1}(z)}{dz} \ f_{2}(z) \ \sin[g(z)] \ dz \ = \text{ not known yet}\tag{2}$$

where $f_{1}$, $f_{2}, g$ are computed numerically and we don't have an explicit or easy equation for them, and as shown above the only difference between the two integrals is in **cosine** versus **sine** functions in last terms.

**Question**: if the value of the first integral ($I_{1}=\Delta$, say, where $\Delta$ is a given quantity) is known already, for example from numerical calculations, but the second one ($I_{2}$) is yet unknown, is there a way to find $I_{2}$ given our knowledge of $I_{1}=\Delta$, and given how closely similar the integrals are?  In other words, can we expression $I_{2}$ in $(2)$ directly in terms of $\Delta$ found in $(1)$, without having to know explicitly $f_{1}, f_{2}, g$ and without having to integrate them directly to find $I_{2}$?

**Note 1**: I guess one could also simplify equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ by writing
$$ I_{1}= \int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}} f(z) \ \cos[g(z)] \ dz \tag{$1'$}$$
$$ I_{2}= \int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}} f(z) \ \sin[g(z)] \ dz \tag{$2'$}$$
where we call $\frac{df_{1}(z)}{dz} f_{2}(z)\equiv f(z)$.

**Note 2**: the same problem in $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be cast in a differential form:

$$ \frac{dI_{1}}{dz}= \frac{df_{1}(z)}{dz} \ f_{2}(z) \ \cos[g(z)] \tag{$1''$}$$
$$ \frac{dI_{2}}{dz}= \frac{df_{1}(z)}{dz} \ f_{2}(z) \ \sin[g(z)]  \tag{$2''$}$$

where again we seek to find $I_{2}$ in terms of $I_{1}=\Delta$, which is known to us a priori, as we don't have an explicit or easy form for $f_{1},f_{2},g$ to integrate directly in $(2)$ or $(2'')$.

In practice, equation $(1'')$ is solved together with another set of $N$ differential equations, to give the answer $\Delta$. Equation $(2'')$, however, is not coupled to that set of $N$ differential equations, and is solved separately. But one notices similarities with $(1'')$, which begs the question.

Comment: Using the notation from (1') and (2'), let me write two new integrals: $\tilde{I}_1 (\alpha) = \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f(z) \cos {\left ( \alpha g(z) \right )} \, dz$ and $\tilde{I}_2 (\alpha) = \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f(z) \sin{\left ( \alpha g(z) \right )} \, dz$. If all functions are nice, then $\tilde{I}_1^\prime (\alpha) = -  \tilde{I}_2 (\alpha)$. Note that $\tilde{I}_1^\prime (1) = I_1$ and $\tilde{I}_2^\prime (1) = I_2$ in your notation. Since you are already using numerical approximation, a finite difference formula $I_2 \approx -(\tilde{I}_1(1 + \delta) - \tilde{I}_1(1))/ \delta$ might work?

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks Evgeny for this clever approach. I had tried something similar but it turned out quite complicated in the end. Yours seems nicer and potentially cleaner. However, when you take $\tilde{I}^{'}_{1}(\alpha)$, shouldn't you get:  $\tilde{I}^{'}_{1}(\alpha)=-\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z) g(z) \sin(\alpha g(z))$, which is not exactly $-\tilde{I}^{'}_{1}(\alpha)$, since there is a new $g(z)$ term in the intergand now?  I am assuming the primes here meant $d/d\alpha$ and that you meant to say $\tilde{I}_{1}(1)=I_{1}$ and $\tilde{I}_{2}(1)=I_{2}$ (without primes) in your comment.Am I correct?

Comment: @Evgeny ... typo in last comment. It should say "... which is not exactly $-\tilde{I}_{2}$, since there is ...."

Comment: @Evgeny Actually I think the choices $\tilde{I}'_{1}(\alpha)=\int f(z) \cos(g(z)+\alpha)dz$ and $\tilde{I}'_{2}(\alpha)=\int f(z) \sin(g(z)+\alpha)dz$ might solve the problem better, without changing the integrands upon taking the derivates (since an extra $g(x)$ won't appear now), don't you agree? And then we proceed similarly in the neighborhood of $\alpha=0$. I can test this and see what happens.

Comment: Ouch, I really messed up differentiating with respect to parameter! While writing a comment was a conscious decision, the situation makes me remember the joke "Don't drink and derive" :) Yes, your choice is much better! Note that you can use higher order finite differences if you require better precision of the final result. But the idea stays the same.

Comment: @Evgeny No worries :) Thanks anyway for the helpful discussion it provided. Could you please give an example of what you meant by higher order finite difference here?  The way I thought about it was a simple derivative like $-(I(\alpha_{0}+\delta)-I(\alpha_{0}))/\delta$, where $\alpha_{0}$ in my example is 0. And I was planning on repeating this ratio with smaller and smaller $\delta$ until it numerically settles, then stop. Isn't this what you meant?

Comment: I've meant something like central difference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Basic_types). It allows you to approach a true value of derivative faster: usual forward difference gives $o(\delta)$ error and central difference gives $o(\delta^2)$ error.

Comment: @Evgeny But I think the central difference on the other hand may cause problem if the function is an oscillatory one, like cosine, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the page on Wikipedia states that in this case central difference will fail. First order finite difference is more robust in that case, but only trial and error will show if there is any drawback to using central difference. If not much is known about $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, I think it's hard to say beforehand will the central difference fail for sure.